# 爵 how do the 'elements' combine to result in 'baron'

Tags: etymology

The 4 elements of this japanese kanji are understood, but I cannot see/intuit any connection between them that might result in the concept of 'baron'. Can anyone shed some light on this mystery?

Comment: If you want the etymology of 「爵」, you should ask without the baron part because this kanji doesn't mean baron. If you want the etymology of the Japanese word for baron you should ask about 男爵

Comment: For this particular question it doesn't matter which forum you ask as there's no phonology to be discussed, but I guess what I meant was that in general, if you're looking for how the character relates to Japanese readings, you should ask on Japanese StackExchange. This is a double post (see https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/34607/%e7%88%b5-meaning-of-the-elements-of-shaku-baron).